# Run OpenVPN --learn-address script as root

Tags: networking, security, vpn, openvpn, tc

I am running an OpenVPN server and need to run a bash script whenever a user gets an IP.

The script is working fine now that i am running OpenVPN as root, but my intention was to run the server as nobody:nogroup to harden the security.

Is there any way of running only this script as root, since it calls tc (traffic control) to shape the user's bandwidth?

Comment: Can't you make the script setuid?

Comment: I don't think setuid works for bash

Comment: Oh, you're right. I forgot about that.

Comment: have the script use sudo with the right settings (NOPASSWD + !requiretty ) ?